# Ruby - Count each word repetition in a string

Tags: ruby, string, algorithm, split, hashmap

I'm trying to solve this exercise from *Ruby Monk* website, which says:

> Try implementing a method called `occurrences` that accepts a string
>   argument and uses `inject` to build a Hash. The keys of this hash should
>   be unique words from that string. The value of those keys should be
>   the number of times this word appears in that string.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
def occurrences(str)
  str.split.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |a, i| a[i] += 1 }
end
```

But I always get this error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

Meanwhile, the solution for this one is quite the same (I think):

```
def occurrences(str)
    str.scan(/\w+/).inject(Hash.new(0)) do |build, word| 
    build[word.downcase] +=1
    build
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so your issue is that you are not returning the correct object from the block. (In your case a `Hash`)

`#inject` works like this

```
[a,b] 
 ^    -> evaluate block 
 |                      |
  -------return-------- V
```

In your solution this is what is happening

```
def occurrences(str)
 str.split.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |a, i| a[i] += 1 }
end
#first pass a = Hash.new(0) and i = word
  #a['word'] = 0 + 1
  #=> 1 
#second pass uses the result from the first as `a` so `a` is now an integer (1). 
#So instead of calling Hash#[] it is actually calling FixNum#[] 
#which requires an integer as this is a BitReference in FixNum.Thus the `TypeError`
```

Simple fix

```
def occurrences(str)
 str.split.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |a, i| a[i] += 1; a }
end
 #first pass a = Hash.new(0) and i = word
  #a['word'] = 0 + 1; a
  #=> {"word" => 1}
```

Now the block returns the `Hash` to be passed to `a` again. As you can see the solution returns the object `build` at the end of the block thus the solution works.

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thanks a lot for your effort.